# RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded - Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous

I've set cron on my Node.js server, where I'm calling every day following function. It evaluates the game (add players some special titles). But when the [CronJob](https://github.com/ncb000gt/node-cron) fires the method, server will crash with error:

```
(null):0
(null)

RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
```

The function:

```
exports.evaluateGamePeriod = function() {
    Game.find({}, function(err, games) {
        for(var i in games) {
            var daysElapsed = Math.floor((Date.now() - games[i].startDate) / (1000*60*60*24));
            if(/*daysElapsed % games[i].period == 0*/ true) {
                User.find({ game: games[i]._id }, function(err, users) {
                    var usersLength = users.length;
                    var count = 0;

                    async.whilst(function () { 
                        return count < usersLength; 
                    }, function (callback) {
                        users[count].evaluatePeriod(function(err, result) {
                            if(result) {
                                User.update(
                                    { _id: result._id },
                                    { $set: { 'stats': result.stats, 'gameTitle.title': result.gameTitle.title } },
                                    function() {
                                        callback();
                                    }
                                );
                            } else {
                                console.log("Users evaluatePeriod method didn't return callback.")
                            }
                        });
                    }, function (err) {
                        //do something when it finishes
                    });
                });
            }
        }
    });
 };
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're missing a `count++` somewhere in your `async.whilst` functions.

You would probably be better off with `async.each`, though.

Also check what's written here: https://github.com/caolan/async#synchronous-iteration-functions